# How can I remove a lock from a linked environment in R?

Tags: r

I tried to run a Bioconductor package (truncateCDF) that modify an environment(hgu133plus2cdf), to remove unwanted probesets, from an affymetrix chip.
Everything went fine, until I got the following message (translated from french):

```
>   assign(cdfname, cdf.env, env=CDF.env)
Error in assign(cdfname, cdf.env, env = CDF.env) : 
  impossible to change the value of a locked link for 'hgu133plus2cdf'
```

The assign function is the ultimate function of the code, that save the changes made to the environment dataset CDF.env to the original environment (hgu133plus2cdf), before using it in analyses of affymetrix chip results; so, it is essential.

My question: what is this locked link to the hgu133plus2cdf environment, and how could I bypass it.

The author of this package successfully run its package around 2005; so I suppose it is a feature introduced since then in R (probably not related to Bioconductor, since assign is a basic R function, reason why I ask this question on this forum instead of Biostar).

I tried to read the docs, but I am overwhelmed, when it comes to environments.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Maybe you could post the original (French) error message as well in case "locked link" didn't have the right inflection for we English speakers.  Also, if you can, `dput` the objects involved so we can reproduce.

Comment: Here is the message in french; as for the objects involved, they are quite big, and I don(t know how to join them to my message; 
<br />
    Erreur dans assign(cdfname, cdf.env, env = CDF.env) : 
      impossible de changer la valeur d'un lien verrouillé pour    'hgu133plus2cdf'

Answer (score 1):

I don't think truncateCDF is from a Bioconductor package; it is a at least not [current](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release). This sounds like [this post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioconductor/2012-June/046069.html) and the next two from the same thread from the Bioconductor mailing list. It is a result of a change in R -- packages now have not-easily-modified name spaces, and these are implemented by locking the environment in which name space symbols are defined. Removing probes is not an essential part of a typical microarray work flow. Please ask on the [Bioconductor mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/) (no subscription required) if you'd like more help.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake; it is not a Bioconductor package, but a package from a published paper, using Bioconductor. The name space that I have to modify is that of 'hgu133plus2cdf' (chip description file, for affymetrix chips), from Bioconductor, which is no longer up to date; that's why I have to modify this environment. (this is a work done for someone else, who will use the corrected environment to analyse his own data).

Comment: Did you follow the approach suggested in the thread to address the error? I don't know what you mean when you say 'no longer up to date'; is there a revised cdf available from Affymetrix?

Comment: I asked a more general question "how to change a cdf environment" on Biostar; basically, I have been answered the same as you; but the guy I am working for is asking for the environment; in fact it is to treat results from xenogrefs between mouse (the host) and human (the donor of the tumor); the aim is to remove probesets that are recognized by both human genes and mouse genes, that cause false positives; since there are quite a lot of these (I have already done that part of the analysis), I think modifying the environment is the only practically feasible method to remove these probesets.

Comment: By the way, I am looking if using a copy of the environment to modifiy, I could bypass the lock.

Comment: If you are worried about false positives, then you would normally want to use all data for normalization, etc., but filter probesets prior to assessing differential expression. This is a straight-forward task on the 'ExpressionSet' that results from, say `just.rma` normalization. But for this type of advice you should be asking on the Bioconductor mailing list. For modifying the locked environment, the thread referenced above indicates that you want to replace `assign` with `assignInNamespace` as a hack. Have you tried that? Let's see your modification and the result of ti.

Comment: Thanks a lot; this substitution of assign seems to have solved my problem.

I shall also try your advices regarding normalization, although I will probably not be involved in that part of the analysis.